# how to send utf-8 to pipes.Template().open() when started on apache?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write some accentuated character via `pipes` standard library. There was no problem with python 2, but fails with python 3 via apache :

On my terminal I have no problem because the file object is automatically initialized with UTF-8 encoding :

```
In[1]: pipes.Template().open('mypipe','w')
Out[1]: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='mypipe' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

But when the same command is started by apache (in a django view), I got :

```
pipes.Template().open('mypipe','w')
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='mypipe' mode='w' encoding='ANSI_X3.4-1968'>
```

Where this 'ANSI_X3.4-1968' comes from and how to force it to 'utf-8' ?

Note : When I use the write(), I can only pass a python3 string not an encoded utf-8 bytes.

Note 2 : file object `__init__()` does not have an 'encoding' parameter, and its attribute 'encoding' is read-only.

Note 3 : The only non-python solution I found is to configure wsgi locale and lang :

```
WSGIDaemonProcess myapp user=apache group=apache processes=4 threads=1 lang=en_US.UTF-8 locale=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: Whats the output of `echo $LC_ALL` (assuming *nix)?

Comment: LC_* are not set, but LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8.

Comment: Set `encoding` with `open`: `pipes.Template().open('mypipe','w', encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: That was the first thing I tried : this open() does not have 'encoding' parameter unfortunately